# How to save some variable values in a file

Tags: matlab, file, save

I want at the end of my program to get the values stored at certain variables and append them to a file let's say "result". I am going to run it several times (for different parameters) at night and then check results in the morning.

Basically, I am looking for something similar to redirection in linux (>>) for matlab.

I am using the diary function to store the whole messages from my program and i want to keep those for verifying later.

But here what I want is just some specific values. So how to do it?

It does not necessary have to be in the same file. If I can get each result in a separate file, that is ok too.

Comment: Thanks, I think save should do. I can adapt the names of files according to my parameters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a combination of `diary` and any function which can append data to a text file, but you have to turn off `diary` before writing. A short example using `save`

```
f='example.txt'
diary(f);
for ix=1:10
    disp(ix);
    diary off %diary off to flush
    save(f,'ix','-append','-ascii')
    diary(f);
end
```

Instead of `save` you can also use `fprntf` or `dlmwrite`

Comment: I tried like this `diary ('resultCommandWindows');
diary off;
filename=['Result_', num2str(param1),  '.txt'];
save filename A B ;` I get no errors but the file is not created. Any idea from where the problem is?

Comment: You created a mat file called `filename`. You have to use the function syntax: `save(filename,'A','B')`

Comment: Thanks, it works. Just one last question, is there a way to put the name of the variable next to its value in the file example `A 15`. Here I am just getting the value.

Comment: I think fprintf would be more adapted to this.